# Isomorphic modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity such that $R^{n}\simeq R^{n}\bigoplus M$ ($R$-module isomorphism), $n$ is fixed, and $n$ is a natural number. Then $M=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ ?

Comment: Are you assuming that the isomorphism holds for _all_ $n$, or just for some $n$? If the former, then is $0$ a natural number for you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Does it really change the situation?

Comment: in this case 0 is a natural number.

Comment: @egreg: If we're assuming that $R^n\cong R^n\oplus M$ for _all_ $n$ including $n=0$, then in particular we're assuming $\{0\}\cong\{0\}\oplus M$, which is a particularly easy argument...

Comment: @HenningMakholm But it's sufficient it holds for a single integer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the localization at the prime ideal $P$; then
$$
R_P^n\cong R_P^n\oplus M^{\vphantom{}}_P
$$
which means $M_P=\{0\}$. (Prove it.)

Since this is for all prime ideals, it follows that…

Comment: it is really difficult for me to understand. Can you explain more details please ?

Comment: @PHUCUONGLEVAN Do you know what a projective module is?

Comment: oh I have not studied that. I have searched google. Perhaps I will read it now.

Comment: @PHUCUONGLEVAN I don't think there is some “more direct” method, because the result is generally false, if the ring is not supposed to be commutative. Did you study localizations?

Comment: I have read projective module. So one has $R^{n}$ is projective so, from hypothesis we get a resuls: $R^{n}\oplus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cong R^{n}\oplus M$. Then

Comment: Can you hence M={0}

Comment: @PHUCUONGLEVAN Actually $R^n$ is free and $M$ is projective. Then note that after localization $M$ also becomes free, and finally can use the rank function in order to get that rank of $M_P$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will read realated knowledge about this problems.